# How to encode array comparison constraints in cvxopt

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, cvxopt

I want to use the python software cvxopt to solve a small testing problem I have (if the software is able to solve this problem, then my boss will be able to use it on a future project). However, I am having trouble figuring out from the documentation how I can encode some constraints that are not of the form Ax = b or Ax < b.

The problem statement is:
x is a numpy array (1-d). Find an array y such that:

```
(1) We minimize ||x-y||^2 
(2) y is increasing throughout (y[k] <= y[k+1] for all k)
(3) the last element of y = the last element of x
(4) y[0] >= 0
```

I see how encoding conditions (3) and (4) can be done, but how can I encode condition (2)?

Thank you,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

First a remark: there is no `A<b` in (continuous) convex-optimization, only `A<=b`.

Your condition (2) is just a pairwise-constraint on the neighbors like:

```
y[0] <= y[1]
y[1] <= y[2]
....
```

To bring it in standard-form:

```
y[0] <= y[1]
<=>
y[0] - y[1] <= 0
```

Now you can use the `A<=b` formulation:

```
A:
1  -1   0   0 ... meaning: y[0] <= y[1] 
0   1  -1   0 ...          y[1] <= y[2]
0   0   1  -1 ...

b:
0
0
0
...
```

If you are not using cvxopt's possibilities to tune KKT-calculations and co. i highly recommend using [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org) (coming from the same academic institution) which is so much easier to use including a lot of functions like `norm(x-y, 2)` and more.... It can also use cvxopt as a solver if needed (but also other open-source solvers like ECOS, SCS).